# Variation in total loss while training the Faster RCNN model using customized data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on object detection model to identify two classes. I am using Faster RCNN on customized dataset in tensorflow api. The dataset contains 20k images (augmented) with two classes. While training the model the loss is not decreasing properly as it reach to 100k steps. It has lot of variation as shown in image. Can someone tell me where i am making mistake.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIWtT.png)